# VB.net - Read .msg file from the shared folder and extract the attachments inside it

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm completely new to VB and I'm trying to extract the attachment which is saved available inside the .msg file using the below code.
Could someone help me if this is the right approach to do this ?

I'm facing below compiler errors. Could someone help me how to resolve this issue ?

1. Outlook.Attachment is not defined.
2. End Sub' must be preceded by a matching 'Sub'
3. Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
4. Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed
5. Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.
6. Type 'Outlook.MailItem' is not defined.

---

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strAttPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strFilePath = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test\"
    strAttPath = "C:\Users\...\extracted attachment\"
    strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "<Doc Name>.msg")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each att In msg.Attachments
                att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.FileName
            Next
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you using VB6, VBA, VBScript or VB.Net? It looks like VBA to me.

Comment: In which case, be careful when tagging your questions as [tag:vb.net] and [tag:vbscript] as they are both very different to [tag:vba].

Comment: The code looks like VBA but the errors appear to be for VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code we use to grab a daily report attachment.  I left a few commented statements in case you might need them (we didn't).

```
Sub Extract_Outlook_Email_Attachments()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = strAttPath  ' SAVE THE ATTACHMENT TO

    'this bit is added to get a shared email
    Set objOwner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("SHARED FOLDER NAME")
    objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Debug.Print "Outlook GB Fulfillment is good."
        Set folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox) 'can use olFolderInbox or olFolderSentMail
    End If

'Write mail to spreadsheet - create named range, from and to dates on the spreadsheet
i = 1
For Each OutlookMail In folder.Items
    '  Debug.Print "SenderEmailAddress: " & OutlookMail.SenderEmailAddress

        'If OutlookMail.SenderEmailAddress = "no-reply@OurCompany.com" Then
    If OutlookMail.subject = "Daily Report" Then
        ' If OutlookMail.SenderName = "no-reply@OurCompany.com" And OutlookMail.Subject = "Daily New Subscriber Plan Election Fulfillment" And OutlookMail.Attachments(1) = "NewSubscriberPlanElectionFulfillment_Subscription.xls" Then
    
        Debug.Print "Received: " & OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Debug.Print "Attach: " & OutlookMail.Attachments(1)
        dateformat = Format(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime, "m-d-yy")
            Debug.Print dateformat

        FName = dateformat & " " & OutlookMail.Attachments(1).fileName
            Debug.Print "FName: " & FName

        Dim strFileExists As String

        strFileExists = Dir(saveFolder & FName)

        If strFileExists = "" Then
'        MsgBox "The selected file doesn't exist"
            Else
'        MsgBox "The selected file exists"
                Exit Sub
        End If
        OutlookMail.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile saveFolder & FName

        Set outAttachment = Nothing

    End If
    Next OutlookMail

    Set folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check out the file path where you try to find the template:

```
 msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
```

The `strFilePath` string may include the file name already:

```
strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "<Doc Name>.msg")
```

Second, make sure attachments are saved using unique file names:

```
att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.FileName
```

The `FileName` string can be the same in different emails. I'd recommend adding IDs or the current time and etc. to the file name to uniquely name attached files on the disk.

Comment: Could you please share me VB.net code for this logic ?

Comment: You need to create such routine on your own according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CreateItemFromTemplate`, you can use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` to open an MSG file.

You also need to add Outlook to your VB.Net project references.